# Bin size seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram, jointplot

I have an array of 90 000 pairs I want to plot with seaborn jointplot.
Is there a way to adjust side histograms bin size? 
Should I try to plot it with an other package?[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to use `marginal_kws` to adjust the bins.  Lifting the example from the seaborn documentation [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html)

**Tested in `python 3.10`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import seaborn as sns

# load sample data
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

g = sns.jointplot(x="petal_length", y="sepal_length", data=iris,
                   marginal_kws=dict(bins=30), s=40)
```

[image]

- without using `marginal_kws`

```py
g = sns.jointplot(x="petal_length", y="sepal_length", data=iris, s=40)
```

[image]